# Excel vba for restricted entry in cells

Tags: excel, vba

My query pertains to Excel.

In a range of cells, the user should be permitted to enter either A or B or C or D or G or X only.  Those group of cells are already having data validation.  Hence, list option cannot be used.

Pl let me have the vba code for this purpose.

Thanks in advance

Pasupathi

**Edit 1**: This is the rest of my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rLook As Range

Set rLook = Range("A14:A40")
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

If Intersect(Target, rLook) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If wf.CountA(rLook) < 2 Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Clear
MsgBox "Only one entry allowed"
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: Can I have your help pl?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? if the user inserts A, B, C, D, G, X , what should happen ? then it should check the line after of `If wf.CountA(rLook) < 2 Then Exit Sub` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want only values of ***Capital*** letters A, B, C, D, G, X in a certtain range of cells.

In that case use the code below, and add it to your relevant Sheet Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WatchRange                  As Range
Dim IntersectRange              As Range

' modify here to the Range you need monitored
Set WatchRange = Range("A1:C10")
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.value
        Case "A", "B", "C", "D", "G", "X"
            ' do something here ...

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Only A , B, C, D, G, X are allowed"

    End Select
Else
   'Do Nothing in Else

End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Shai.  I already have a vba code in the worksheet.  How your code can be linked with this code? Can you pl guide me?

Comment: upload the rest of your worksheet code to your post, so I can see where to paste it. Or you can copy the contents of this sub, and add it to your `Worksheet_Change` event

Comment: The following is the rest of the code                                                         Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rLook As Range
   
    Set rLook = Range("A14:A40")
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    If Intersect(Target, rLook) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If wf.CountA(rLook) < 2 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Clear
        MsgBox "Only one entry allowed"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: @Pasupathi this code is hard to read this way, please update your Post with this code

Comment: I don't know as to how to update my post.  Hence, I've given the rest of the code along with my query which is at the top.  Pl look into and guide.  Thanks

Comment: I don't know as to how to update my post.  Hence, I've given the rest of the code along with my query which is at the top.  Pl look into and guide.  Thanks